# What is the mkdict command and what does it do? (It came in distro but has no man page or help)

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, command

When using tab completion for mkdir I found a binary existing called mkdict. But I can't find a man page or other details. A Google search only yields info on a python library with this name, but I don't think this command can be that. What is it?

I am running Oracle Linux 8 in a VM, without GUI (just cli). Here is some results of commands I tried to find info:

Location:

```
$ which mkdict
/usr/sbin/mkdict
```

Trying to find something:

```
$whatis mkdict
mkdict: nothing appropriate.

$man mkdict
No manual entry for mkdict

$help mkdict
-bash: help: no help topics match 'mkdict'

$mkdict --help
-d, --decrompressdecompress

$dnf info mkdict*
Error: No matching Packages to list
```

If I try to run it, then nothing really seems to happen. Perhaps it is waiting for input. The terminal just sits trying to run it until I do a Ctrl-Break.

A Google search for mkdict + linux only gives results on a Python package of the same name, at least in the results I reviewed. But it seems unlikely this is that package, which is has apparently little downloads from PyPI.

What is mkdict and what does it do or is for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googling for `/usr/sbin/mkdict` (because it's really interesting that it's in `sbin` and not `bin`) finds [this bugreport](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/978793)

> No man pages found for /usr/sbin/mkdict & /usr/sbin/packer. These binaries are part of the cracklib-dicts RPM package, but no man pages are included in RPM package.

from Red Hat, which fits Oracle Linux.

*Cracklib* does seem to have a Python port, but was originally C, and apparently can be used to validate passwords by rejecting those that can be easily cracked. The beginning of the original README goes

> CrackLib is a library containing a C function (well, lots of functions
> really, but you only need to use one of them) which may be used in a
> "passwd"-like program.
>
> The idea is simple: try to prevent users from choosing passwords that
> could be guessed by "Crack" by filtering them out, at source.
>
> CrackLib is an offshoot of the the version 5 "Crack" software, and
> contains a considerable number of ideas nicked from the new software.
>
> At the time of writing, Crack 5 is incomplete (still awaiting purchase
> of my home box) - but I though I could share this with you.
>
> [ Incidentally, if Dell or anyone would like to "donate" a Linuxable
> 486DX2-66MHz box (EISA/16Mb RAM/640MB HD/AHA1740) as a development
> platform for Crack, I'd be more than grateful to hear from you.  8-) ]

It should be easy to find out by looking at the "binaries" if Oracle Linux is using the Python port, or the original.

Comment: Thank you! Based on your answer I did a `file /usr/sbin/mkdict` which on reflection I should have tried right away. Turns out its a symlink to cracklib-format, which does in fact have a man page itself. But its neither python nor C, but a shell script. Interesting.

Comment: So have a look at what's inside, and if it's calling compiled C code, or Python code. Or have a look at other files in these packages.